# NSWindow redraw issues/flickers when resized

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, nswindow

I recently noticed that some controls (NSTableView & NSOutlineView) in my app flicker when I resize the app's window.

I can't figure out why that happens. I reduced the app to the bare minimum: a single document window controller with a window that contains an outline view and a button. No background processing, not loading the document data, etc.

Here is a screenshot showing UI fragments during resizing the window:

[image: Sample screenshot]

Notice fragment of the outline view at the top, the white background, and the offset window shadow.

There's also a Core Graphics related warning in the console (see below). Not sure if it's related to the problem.

The app is running on Mac OS X 10.10.1, deployment target and base SDK set to 10.9.

Console output (not a crash):

```
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const: conn 0x22833 token 0x10dfffffffff3823
<Warning>: Backtrace (at 4250.73):
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  0   CoreGraphics                        0x00007fff986f5215 CGSBacktraceCreate + 59
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  1   CoreGraphics                        0x00007fff98714688 _ZN16CGSUpdateManager14disable_updateEv + 84
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  2   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e4e2de5 -[NSWindow disableScreenUpdatesUntilFlush] + 127
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  3   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e4a2250 -[NSView _gainedLayerTreeHostAncestor] + 385
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e4a20ae -[NSView _recursiveGainedLayerTreeHostAncestor] + 27
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e4a667a -[NSScroller _recursiveGainedLayerTreeHostAncestor] + 103
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e70da56 -[NSScroller _setSurfaceBacked:] + 213
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e67324f -[NSScrollView setScrollerStyle:] + 304
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8ed0af27 +[NSScrollerImpPair _updateAllScrollerImpPairsForNewRecommendedScrollerStyle:] + 426
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b36fcbc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b2611b4 _CFXNotificationPost + 3140
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  11  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b5f8ea1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b2d154c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b2c3655 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b2c2e0e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b2c2838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  16  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9980043f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  17  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff998000be ReceiveNextEventCommon + 179
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  18  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff997ffffb _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e4266d1 _DPSNextEvent + 964
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e425e80 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e419e23 -[NSApplication run] + 594
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e4052d4 NSApplicationMain + 1832
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  23  MyApp                               0x00000001000022eb main + 75
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  24  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff97a025c9 start + 1
```

Comment: So what's the question; how to avoid flicker or how to solve the crash?  If it's the latter then we'll need to see some code.

Comment: @Droppy The question is what could possibly cause the flickering. The console output is not a crash, merely a warning. I can't tell if it is directly related (but likely).

Comment: I would say it was related; unless you are doing lots of custom drawing in the views, you shouldn't notice any flicker.

Comment: No custom drawing, just the window as you see in the screenshot. I can't reproduce this in another test project so I suspect maybe an Xcode build setting for this project or another library that's interfering with drawing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For reference, I found the root cause, although I can't explain it.

In `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` I was initializing a shared instance of a window controller and showing its window by calling `showWindow:nil`. That window happened to contain an `NSTableView`. This table view caused the flickering in the other outline view (in an unrelated window).

Why? I honestly have no idea. I removed all controls from the window and added an empty table view right from the Interface Builder palette → problem occurs. After removing the table view the problem disappeared.

The solution was to not open the window right away in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`. Instead I added a menu to open it at a later time (it was a window with debug information anyway).

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to bring that window front after a very small delay, i.e.:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    if (WSPreferences.currentApplication.showActivityWindow) {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794135/nswindow-redraw-issues-flickers-when-resized
        //
        [self performSelector:@selector(makeKeyAndOrderFront:) withObject:self afterDelay:0.1];
    }
}
```

Comment: so you ran into the same problem? I wonder what's causing this in the first place. Maybe a bug that was introduced with Yosemite?...